# Magento2 composer update in wrong path

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

In Magento2 when I am running

`composer update` with non root user I am getting the error like:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.31
    Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

    Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Nothing to install or update


      [ErrorException]
      file_put_contents(/usr/bin/vendor/composer/installed.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied


    update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

and I run the same command with root user there is no error but the files generated are in the wrong path:

```
Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
[root@s132-148-137-252 public_html]# ls /usr/bin/vendor/composer/
autoload_classmap.php  autoload_namespaces.php  autoload_psr4.php  autoload_real.php  autoload_static.php  ClassLoader.php  installed.json  LICENSE
[root@s132-148-137-252 public_html]#
```

How I can fix this?

**Update**
As suggested by Rob006
I reinstalled Composer as non root user, but now I am facing another issue:

when running composer update I am getting this exception error:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI

    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):                                                                                                                                                                        Authentication required (repo.magento.com):                                                                                                                                                                        Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username:

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Aborted
```

I am not getting a chance to give username.

Comment: Delete `vendor` directory (as root) and run `composer install` again (as **not** root). And do not run composer as root in future.

Comment: Thanks will try that and update. should I uninstall composer before installing again.

Comment: Nope, Composer is only a tool for installing dependencies in your project. There is probably nothing wrong with Composer itself, you just need to install dependencies in a right way and removing `vendor` should be enough for cleanup your current mess. :)

Comment: as per instruction for composer install i should move composer.phar  to /usr/local/bin/composer - is that ok? or should I move to Magento root?

Comment: It is only a executable, so it depends how you want to use it. Moving it to `/usr/local/bin/composer` will work like global installation and allow you to run it like `composer install` from any place in your system. So this is probably the most convenient option.

Comment: Hi Rob - I have updated the question for the error I am getting.

Comment: "*I am not getting a chance to give username.*" - This is probably because you're using PHP for SAPI instead of CLI. You should check your server configuration, it looks like you've messed up something.

Comment: There were two issues. as you stated SAPI instead of CLI was one issue. as I added the authentication in auth.json then I started getting STD out error. but then I moved the /usr/bin/php to php.bak and created a symlink for cli version of php.